# How can I remove COM ports by command line (w/o installing)

Tags: command-line, serial-port, windows-7-x64

The setup: An automated test station, built around a Windows 7 PC. The UUT (Unit Under Test) are connected and disconnected often, creating many COM ports.

The Problem: The test is searching for the device at a specific COM port, requiring the user to manually remove the "ghost" com ports.

The question: Since the software is used by several test stations in parallel, at a production floor, I cannot install additional software (e.g. Devcon, part of Windows SDK). Is there a command line option to remove the COM ports?

Comment: There is something for that in the Windows Driver SDK I think. But you'd have to install that too.

Comment: instead of having to remove the *residual* ports all the time - you can just prevent them from being created https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_apgc_hardware_developer_support_team/2013/11/09/to-ignore-a-usb-devices-serial-number/

Comment: Thank you for this idea, I'll test it.

Comment: @Alex-P Thank you for this idea, but the problem occurs even with the same device as it disconnects and reconnects.
I tried to change the registry keys, yet:
1) This is not advised (even by the author of the blog)
2) It did not prevent the "hidden" ports to be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [This blog entry](http://blog.cognitioninfotech.com/2009/01/how-to-clear-or-reset-com-port.html)

The only thing that actually worked for me is not the intended solution... But it fit the case at hand:

1. Created a batch file at C:\windows\system32
2. The content:

   REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\COM Name Arbiter" /v ComDB /t REG_BINARY /d 0206 /f
3. The actual value of the registry key (0206 in my example) can either be read from that key (use regedit) or calculated from binary:

com8 com7 com6 com5 com4 com3 com2 com1 com16 com15 com14 com13 com12 com11 com10 com9
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0

since I wished to keep com1, com2, com10 and com11 - 0000 0011 0000 0110 - which stand for 0206

4. executing this batch file will remove the unnecessary comports while leaving the one's I intended

*The batch should be at system32 to be executed as elevated (administrator)
*for more details refer to [this PDF](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_132_Re-Assigning_COM_Port_Numbers_Using_Registry.pdf)